# VB.net Round off Decimal number to the nearest integer

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to VB.net coding i would like to know how to round of a decimal number to the nearest integer
Eg. **X= (5-2/2) = 1.5**
but I need only as 1.

Thank you.

Comment: The nearest integer for 1.5 is 2 (usually). Or do you always want to round down? Anyway, you either need [Math.Round()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round) or [Math.Floor()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.floor).

Comment: look into Math.Round & there are options to round up or down from 0.5

Comment: also (5-2/2) is 4, not 1.5

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [integer division operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/integer-division-operator)  if you just want to discard any remainder:

```
Dim resultValue As Integer = (5-2) \ 2
```

Note that this is one of the differences between VB.NET and C#, in C# the normal division operator will always apply integer division, so discard the remainder.

You have other options:

```
resultValue = CInt(Math.Floor((5-2) / 2))
resultValue = CInt(Math.Round((5-2) / 2, MidpointRounding.ToZero))
```

Comment: It depends on how the OP defines "nearest integer". He might want 1.5 to become 1 but 1.6 to become 2. In which case, `Math.Round()` would be the way to go.

Comment: Never heard of that operator in VB. +1

Comment: @41686d6564: since he wants to get 1 from 1.5 i assume that he means the largest integral value less than or equal, so same as what `Math.Floor` returns(as double).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Math.Round( (5-2)/2, 0)
```

..and look into the options for the [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-6.0#system-math-round(system-double-system-midpointrounding)) with the `MidpointRounding` param, which you can set to influence rounding when the result ends with .5. Here are some of the available options:

```
Math.Round((5 - 2) / 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
Math.Round((5 - 2) / 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven)
```

Check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding) (or trial & error) to see which best suits your needs.

Or if you always want either the integer below or the integer above, then also check out `Math.Floor` and `Math.Ceiling` functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the floor function. For example, `double floor(double x);`, the floor function returns the largest integer that is smaller than or equal to x.

Comment: That's C# syntax, but the question is asking for VB.NET.